# importlib.import_module with python

Tags: python, import

Hello there I would like some to address me properlly on how to use importlib.import_module

I am attempting to import a module using the lib: but what I am getting is:

this is the example of my class:

```
class Main:
    def __init__:
        self.appFileName=None
        self.appFileToPass=None


    def decrypt(self, string):
        return cryptocode.decrypt(string, localKey)

    def decrypFile(self, file):

        # decrpts the file 
        newFile=""
        with open(file) as f:
            line = f.readline()
            while line:
                line = f.readline()
                newFile+=str(self.decrypt(line))


        # creats a random name 
        alphaName=f"{''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(9,12)))}"
        self.appFileName=f"{alphaName}.py"
        self.appFileToPass=alphaName

        # save file locally 
        with open(self.appFileName, 'w') as myprints:
            myprints.write(newFile)
        myprints.close()
        

    def run(self):
        self.decrypFile("fileToDecrypt")
        app=importlib.import_module(self.appFileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main=Main()
    main.run()
```

the error :

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <bound method runApp of <__main__.my class>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Myfile.py", line 4747, in runApp
    app=importlib.import_module(self.appFileName))
  File "C:Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appR'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excerpt from the error I received:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eWtZWhAbv.py'; 'eWtZWhAbv' is not a package
```

So, it looks for a module `eWtZWhAbv.py`.
From the file system perspective, this module corresponds to the `./eWtZWhAbv/py.py` file and not `./eWtZWhAbv.py`.

This happens because the dot is a delimiter between package members.
The solution then would be to swap `eWtZWhAbv.py` with `eWtZWhAbv` (without extension).

To fix this, remove the `.py` extension:

```
--- app=importlib.import_module(self.appFileName)
+++ appModule = os.path.splitext(self.appFileName)[0]
+++ app = importlib.import_module(appModule)
```

This should make the trick!

Comment: Thank you Pavel, do you have another approch in mind, by any chance?, I have tried with self.appFileToPass and with your suggestiong and still getting ane error now this time is different:     SyntaxError: invalid syntax (audfZzjFhC.py, line 526)

Comment: In this case, the **target file** seems to be incorrect. You can check it by manually importing it into an app or interactive session - and you should see the same error.

Comment: you are correct, I will fix the target file. and apply your solution